# Select Field display in weird ways

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Here is a TAG

[image]

The white block is the select field

Here is the select field selected

[image]

Here is the code

[image]

Why is it expanding out of it's limit ? there is nothing fancy there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are to use

selectfield.setHtml()  and set it to a String.

It will destroy display and display the String ahs the value.
It's better to use setText() to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your layout type.Which layout you are working with?Try it after removing layout config and add

```
xtype:'textfield',
anchor:50%,
itemId:'field'
```